# Multiple configuration tree to one class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

i have this in Application.yaml:

```
  override:
    email:
      enabled: true
      value: "test@mycompany.com"
    phone:
      enabled: true
      value: "+420666666666"
```

How do I make a single class configuration with these values?
I tried this:

```
public class RecipientOverrideConfig {

    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties("override.email")
    @Data
    public class EmailOverride{

        Boolean enabled;
        String value;

    }

    @Configuration
    @ConfigurationProperties("override.phone")
    @Data
    public class SmsOverride{

        Boolean enabled;
        String value;

    }
}
```

But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Take a look : https://www.boraji.com/spring-boot-configurationproperties-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making the whole class a `ConfigurationProperties`

```
@ConfigurationProperties("override")
public class RecipientOverrideProperties {
    private OverrideConfig email;
    private OverrideConfig phone;

    public class OverrideConfig {
        private Boolean enabled;
        private String value;
    }

    // getters and setters were omitted for brevity
}
```

And then autowire that into your configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class RecipientOverrideConfig {
    @Autowired // or even better, use constructor injection
    private RecipientOverrideProperties overrideProperties;
}
```

Comment: this is good approach but its more like static. i.e adding another type suppose fax will make change to java class as well

Comment: @Noshaf If one's working in a private or company internal project, then changes to a class should not be a big deal

Comment: yes agree it depends.in that situation the solution works perfectly